# How To Select Records in a Status Between Timestamps? T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a T-SQL Quotes table and need to be able to count how many quotes were in an open status during past months.

The dates I have to work with are an '`Add_Date`' timestamp and an '`Update_Date`' timestamp. Once a quote is put into a '`Closed_Status`' of '`1`' it can no longer be updated.  Therefore, the '`Update_Date`' effectively becomes the `Closed_Status` timestamp.

I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to select all open quotes that were open in a particular month.

Here's a few example records:

```
Quote_No   Add_Date   Update_Date  Open_Status  Closed_Status
001        01-01-2016  NULL         1            0
002        01-01-2016  3-1-2016     0            1
003        01-01-2016  4-1-2016     0            1
```

The desired result would be:

```
Year  Month  Open_Quote_Count
2016  01     3
2016  02     3
2016  03     2
2016  04     1
```

I've hit a mental wall on this one, I've tried to do some `case when` filtering but I just can't seem to figure this puzzle out.  Ideally I wouldn't be hard-coding in dates because this spans years and I don't want to maintain this once written.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you want months to be displayed even if the counter is 0 or not?

Comment: Note that you probably mean `DateTime`, `DateTime2` or `Date` but **not `Timestamp`** as `TimeStamp` is actually an auto incrementing binary value and has nothing to do with actual date/time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing this by month.  So, three options come to mind:

- A list of all months using `left join`.
- A recursive CTE.
- A number table.

Let me show the last:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select format(dateadd(month, n.n, q.add_date), 'yyyy-MM') as yyyymm,
       count(*) as Open_Quote_Count
from quotes q join
     n
     on (closed_status = 1 and dateadd(month, n.n, q.add_date) <= q.update_date) or
        (closed_status = 0 and dateadd(month, n.n, q.add_date) <= getdate()) 
group by format(dateadd(month, n.n, q.add_date), 'yyyy-MM')
order by yyyymm;
```

This does assume that each month has at least one open record.  That seems reasonable for this purpose.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff, it worked and solved my problem.  I'm thankful, but do want to understand how/why the row_number() order by section works.  Any reference you would recommend?  I'm very impressed with your skill.

Comment: @SDS . . . `master..spt_values` is a large'ish table (thousands of rows) that is often used for generating numbers in SQL.  In fact, one of the columns is sequential, but I cannot remember which, so I just use `row_number()` to generate a sequential value.  If you run only the CTE, you can see that it just produces a bunch of numbers, starting at 0.

Comment: I've been using this for a couple of months now and it turns out there is an issue.  Basically this is returning a cumulative number, so January was fine, but then Feb is really Jan + Feb, and March is Jan+Feb+March, etc. etc.  Now that we're in July we've found this out.  Any suggestions on how to correct this?  Thank you!

Comment: @SDS . . . Can you ask another question with sample data and desired results?

Comment: I have posted a new question with a full data set and the desired results here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439853/t-sql-count-of-records-in-status-for-previous-months
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`datepart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to extract parts of a date, so something like:

```
select datepart(year, add_date) as 'year',
       datepart(month, date_date) as 'month',
       count(1)
from theTable
where open_status = 1
group by datepart(year, add_date), datepart(month, date_date)
```

Note: this counts for the starting month and primarily to show the use of `datepart`.

Comment: As the OP mentions `select all open quotes that *were* open`, this will not solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Updated as misunderstood the initial request.

Consider following test data:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE 
(
    Quote_No VARCHAR(3),
    Add_Date DATE,
    Update_Date DATE,
    Open_Status INT,
    Closed_Status INT
)

INSERT INTO @test (Quote_No, Add_Date, Update_Date, Open_Status, Closed_Status)
VALUES ('001', '20160101', NULL, 1, 0)
     , ('002', '20160101', '20160301', 0, 1)
     , ('003', '20160101', '20160401', 0, 1)
```

Here is a recursive solution, that doesn't rely on system tables BUT also performs poorer. As we are talking about months and year combinations, the number of recursions will not get overhand.

```
;WITH YearMonths AS
(
    SELECT YEAR(MIN(Add_Date)) AS [Year]
        , MONTH(MIN(Add_Date)) AS [Month]
        , MIN(Add_Date) AS YMDate
    FROM @test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,1,YMDate))
        , MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,1,YMDate))
        , DATEADD(MONTH,1,YMDate)
    FROM YearMonths
    WHERE YMDate <= SYSDATETIME()
)
SELECT [Year]
    , [Month]
    , COUNT(*) AS Open_Quote_Count
FROM YearMonths ym
INNER JOIN @test t
ON (
    [Year] * 100 + [Month] <= CAST(FORMAT(t.Update_Date, 'yyyyMM') AS INT)
    AND t.Closed_Status = 1
    )
OR (
    [Year] * 100 + [Month] <= CAST(FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyMM') AS INT)
    AND t.Closed_Status = 0
    )
GROUP BY [Year], [Month]
ORDER BY [Year], [Month]
```

Statement is longer, also more readable and lists all year/month combinations to date.

Take a look at [Date and Time Data Types and Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) for SQL-Server 2008+

and [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: As the OP mentions `select all open quotes that *were* open`, this will not solve the question.

Comment: Wasn't clearly stated at beginning. I just realized what was meant, after reading Gordon's answer. Updated my script.