# T-SQL Count of Records in Status for Previous Months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, count

I have a T-SQL Quotes table and need to be able to count how many quotes were in an open status during past months.

The dates I have to work with are an 'Add_Date' timestamp and an 'Update_Date' timestamp. Once a quote is put into a 'Won' or 'Loss' columns with a value of '1' in that column it can no longer be updated. Therefore, the 'Update_Date' effectively becomes the Closed_Status timestamp.

Here's a few example records:

```
Quote_No   Add_Date   Update_Date  Open_Quote  Win  Loss
001        01-01-2016  NULL         1           0    0
002        01-01-2016  3-1-2016     0           1    0
003        01-01-2016  4-1-2016     0           0    1
```

Here's a link to all the data here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1T3IxQ2ZKRDhNd1k

[I asked this question previously this year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416900/how-to-select-records-in-a-status-between-timestamps-t-sql) and have been using the following code:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select format(dateadd(month, n.n, q.add_date), 'yyyy-MM') as yyyymm,
       count(*) as Open_Quote_Count
from quotes q join
     n
     on (closed_status = 1 and dateadd(month, n.n, q.add_date) <= q.update_date) or
        (closed_status = 0 and dateadd(month, n.n, q.add_date) <= getdate()) 
group by format(dateadd(month, n.n, q.add_date), 'yyyy-MM')
order by yyyymm;
```

The problem is this code is returning a cumulative value. So January was fine, but then Feb is really Jan + Feb, and March is Jan+Feb+March, etc. etc.  It took me a while to discover this and the numbers returned now way, way off and I'm trying to correct them.

From the full data set the results of this code are:

```
Year-Month  Open_Quote_Count
2017-01      153
2017-02      265
2017-03      375
2017-04      446
2017-05      496
2017-06      560
2017-07      609
```

The desired result would be how many quotes were in an open status during that particular month, not the cumulative :

```
Year-Month  Open_Quote_Count
2017-01     153
2017-02     112
2017-03     110
2017-04     71
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Which version of sql server?

Comment: @scsimon, this is a T-SQL query through a web-based ERP client, I believe it's 2012 but not 100% sure on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, LAG() would be a good fit here

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Year-Month] varchar(50),[Open_Quote_Count] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2017-01',153)
,('2017-02',265)
,('2017-03',375)
,('2017-04',446)
,('2017-05',496)
,('2017-06',560)
,('2017-07',609)

Select *
      ,NewValue = [Open_Quote_Count] - lag([Open_Quote_Count],1,0) over (Order by [Year-Month]) 
 From @YourTable   --<< Replace with your initial query
```

**Returns**

```
Year-Month  Open_Quote_Count    NewValue
2017-01     153                 153
2017-02     265                 112
2017-03     375                 110
2017-04     446                 71
2017-05     496                 50
2017-06     560                 64
2017-07     609                 49
```

Comment: you are not missing anything - the answer is brilliant because it's so simple.  Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @SDS That's a relief.  I suspect you were just over-thinking it.  We're all guilty of that.  :)